# Delete old activity instance when starting a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm looking to delete/remove an old activity instance when a new instance (of same activity) is created, however I need to maintain all other activities in back-stack (therefore FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP won't suffice).

E.g. say I have activities A, B & C.
I start: A -> B -> C -> B.
On the start of the second B activity I need to remove the existing B activity.
Therefore I now have: A -> C -> B running...

Any help appreciated.

Comment: try `finish()` before starting each of the activities.

Comment: If I follow you, finish() will kill the activity therefore back-stack would only ever have the current activity running right?

Comment: yes ofcourse..isnt it that you want?

Comment: no, as stated I want A -> C -> B running, I want to preserve the backstack and remove only the duplicate instance.

Comment: @ScottishUser I need exactly the same. Did you find the answer?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I ended up going with below solution, moving the activity back to top of stack which worked for my purpose. You could go further and remove/finish() the activity at this point and then restart which would essentially remove the old instance and start a fresh one if that was desired. This would give exactly the pattern I outlined initially.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that deleting the activity is not as easy as I would have imagined therefore not a complete answer but I'm going to go with using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. This will not kill the existing activity but instead move it to top of stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will allow for the activity navigation outlined above.

I'm still interested if someone knows of a means to clear the actual activity.

Comment: Won't it bring the existing instance to the front, instead of creating the new one?
What if I need to close the older existing instance, and start a new one?

Comment: Yep I finally went with above, might even a bit of a hack but you could move to top of stack, finish () and then restart the activity that way you would have killed the old instance and have a new one?

Comment: You should use this in combination with onNewIntent() if you want to update the activity at all.

Answer (score 19):

You could use the `Intent` flags to remove the earlier task. Hopefully this helps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished.

Comment: thanks, as A, B & C are all running under the same task, the above suggestion kills the task therefore all activities within. Essentially it aborts the app.

Comment: @ScottishUser, oh right, I completely misunderstood the question. What if you use the `singleTop` attribute for `B`?

Comment: singleTop would only work if the activity was at top of task, however the duplicate activity will not necessarily be at top of task (see above A, B, C example) therefore a duplicate activity will result. Thanks again.

Answer (score 15):

I am able to do that by overriding onNewIntent

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {


        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        msgIntent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(msgIntent);
        finish();
        return;

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

make activity single task

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Last line "super.onNewIntent(intent)" is unreachable because there is a return right before that line.

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
  protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
       
  }
```

In manifest file

```
    <activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" > 
   </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved mine

```
@Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
   
}
```