# Up Navigation not launching parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I have two activities `A` and `B` where A is the parent of B. Now I show a notification that launches B. when I tap on the notification, B launches. Then I click on the *up* button. It works finr when activity A is in the backstack but otherwise the app Just closes and does not launch activity A.

#### My Setup.

I have declared A as Parent of B in Manifest with A in *SingleTop* launchMode

```
<activity
        android:name=".A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="<packegeName>.Home" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".A"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".A" />
    </activity>
```

This is the notification Intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
                                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

In Activity B :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ....
}
```

#### What I've tried

In order to debug I've tried manually triggering this up navigation in Activity B's `onResume`, with all of these :

#### 1)

```
Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
    // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
    // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
            // Navigate up to the closest parent
            .startActivities();
} else {
    // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
    // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
}
```

#### 2)

```
onNavigateUp();
```

#### 3)

```
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

But none of these seem to work when Activity A is not in the Backstack, the app just exits.

I have scoured SO and Google (even bing!) looking for an answer and tried everything I could find to no avail. As there is no error or log output, I also have no idea how to debug this.

Any solution or tips on finding out the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned that you had tried approaches 1, 2, and 3 inside of Activity B's onResume. I think you should be doing those inside of onMenuItemSelected so you can intercept the click event on the home icon. To me 1 looks like the correct way to do this.

Comment: You could also use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, but I think what you are doing is more correct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32427484/6526330

Comment: @Dr.Nitpick I'm doing that in onResume because for testing purposes because my app requires to instantly go to the parent if a certain condition is not met. Anyways I've tried all 3 in `onMenuItemSelected`. but its the same. the app just exits.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping for the easy out :P Just curious, do you return true or false in `onMenuItemSelected` when the home icon is clicked?

Comment: `case android.R.id.home: NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this); return true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the approach described for [Synthesize a new Back Stack for Deep Links](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

You will have use TaskStackBuild to build the back stack and get the PendingIntent when starting on Activity B.

Check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvIlVsXxXmY) video from Android Design Patterns explains it simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. I was looking at the [wrong docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp). Now its perfect.

Answer (score 3):

@pablobu's answer worked for me but I want to add a little more explanation of what I found.

*Damn those docs are confusing*

Where I initially got confused was due to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp) :

> If your activity provides any intent filters that allow other apps to start the activity, you should implement the onOptionsItemSelected() callback such that if the user presses the Up button after entering your activity from another app's task, your app starts a new task with the appropriate back stack before navigating up.
>
> ```
>     if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
>         // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
>         // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
>         TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
>                 // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
>                 .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
>                 // Navigate up to the closest parent
>                 .startActivities();
>     } else {
>         // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
>         // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
>         NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
>     }
> ```

I was of the impression that this would generate the backstack for me. But there is a difference.

`NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)` will return true only if the current activity is inside another app's task. As for launching from a notification, this will be false, so the task-stack-building code does not execute.

The correct way, is to build the backstack when generating the notification and passing it as a pending intent. From [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#CreateBackStack) :

> when a notification takes the user to an activity deep in your app hierarchy, you can use this code to create a PendingIntent that starts an activity and inserts a new back stack into the target task.
>
> ```
> Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
> // Use TaskStackBuilder to build the back stack and get the PendingIntent
> PendingIntent pendingIntent =
>         TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
>                         // add all of DetailsActivity's parents to the stack,
>                         // followed by DetailsActivity itself
>                         .addNextIntentWithParentStack(detailsIntent)
>                         .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
> NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
> builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `public boolean shouldUpRecreateTask(Intent targetIntent)` method in activity and always return `true`.